# Karate: match with parametrized regex

Tags: karate

I didn't find the right way to write a match with regexp cointaining a variable:

```
* def getYear =
  """
  function() {
    var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
    var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy');
    var date = new java.util.Date();
    return sdf.format(date);
  } 
  """
* def currentYear = getYear()
* def testmatch = { gencode: '#("000" + currentYear + "0000012345")' }
* match testmatch == { gencode: '#regex "[0-9]{3}" + currentYear + "[0-9]{10}"' }
```

There is a way to do this?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, normally when you are doing matches like this, regex is un-necessary, because you might as well do an exact match.

But anyway this is the solution, refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#self-validation-expressions

```
* def isValidYear = function(x){ return new RegExp("[0-9]{3}" + currentYear + "[0-9]{10}").test(x) }
* assert isValidYear('00020190000012345')
* match testmatch == { gencode: '#? isValidYear(_)' }
```

Comment: I can't make a exact match. My `testmatch` is a service response and i can't know which is the current year (or day, or hour, and so on). Thanks for the response, that soves my problem!