# Trouble using #regex marker

Tags: karate

I'm having trouble constructing a proper #regex marker.

I'm trying to match on a couple of date formats in my response JSON:

`"created": "2017-03-23T14:16:25.854Z"
"modified": "2018-06-21T05:38:37.978Z"`

I've attempted the following markers:

`'#regex [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z'
'#regex [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.'
'#regex \d+-\d+-\d+.\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+.'`

All 3 forms appear to be correct (according to rubular.com). I've also played around with escaping characters that might be problematic. The only one I been able to get tot work so far is:

`[0-9-T:.Z]+`

But this feels a little "loose" of a pattern match.

Basically I'm attempting this:

`* def meta = { created: '#regex[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.]', modified: '#regex[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}.]' }
And match each response ==
  """
  {
    id: '#regex [a-z0-9]+',
    name: '#string',
    type: '<Type>',
    meta: #(meta),
    integration_id: '#uuid'
  }
  """`

Get an error similar to this:

`KarateException: objects-api.feature:40 - path: $[0].meta.created, actual: '2016-11-30T20:48:16.782Z', expected: '#regex [0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[0-9]+', reason: regex match failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, why don't you parse the dates into java `Date` objects and that will open up more possibilities such as being able to compare 2 dates.

Here are good examples: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54133126/143475
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938480/143475

That said, I think you missed having to escape the backslash-es, this is a Java thing and is mentioned in the docs. So this works:

```
* def date = '2017-03-23T14:16:25.854Z'
* match date == '#regex \\d+-\\d+-\\d+.\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+.'
* match date == '#regex [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{3}Z'
```

The Karate JS engine also supports the `RegExp` JS object, so see if this example gives you some solutions as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54768838/143475

EDIT, this works for me as well:

```
* def meta = { created: '#regex \\d+-\\d+-\\d+.\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+.', modified: '#regex \\d+-\\d+-\\d+.\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+.' }
* def response = [{ meta: { created: '2017-03-23T14:16:25.854Z', modified: '2018-06-21T05:38:37.978Z' } }]
* match each response == { meta: '#(meta)' }
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Your simplified examples works as expected, however when I attempt to put the regex in an  'in-line' short-cut is when it fails to match the regex:

    And match each response ==
      """
      {
        id: '#regex [a-z0-9]+',
        name: '#string',
        type: '<Type>',
        meta: { created: '#regex \\d+-\\d+-\\d+.\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+.', modified: '#regex \\d+-\\d+-\\d+.\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+.' },
        integration_id: '#uuid'
      }
      """

Comment: @kpschmidt see my edit. if you still can't get this to work, kindly follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Another piece of info... I create a Dynamic Scenario outline, which works fine to iterate over values. If I go back to a statically defined outline, the regex works as expect. It's looking more like the use of the dynamic scenario outline that is throwing things off.

Comment: I believe I am following the process. If you feel that my doing root cause analysis is not of value to this question, then yes, I can mark this as "accepted", because in the basic sense of "working", it does, with the exception of utilization of a dynamic scenario outline. Would like like me to file an issue for that?

Comment: @kpschmidt yes and yes. when I say process, it is the link I posted above and will repeat here again to clear any confusion: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue