# How to call validate.js and use it in feature file (to verify the response)?

Tags: karate, validator.js

How to call validate.js and use it in feature file (to verify a specific part of the response)?

I am trying to use https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js which is a library with some awesome validators out-of-the-box.

While reading the Karate documentation there is a way to read / call and read .js files, so I taught there has to be a way to do this. https://intuit.github.io/karate/#schema-validation

I gotten this far but: ReferenceError: "isNumeric" is not defined in  at line number 1

```
var validator = require('validator');
* def isNumeric = validator.isNumeric ;

In a scenario:
    And match each response/list/costs/numberX == '#? isNumeric(_)'
```

I feel I am really close...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of now Karate supports only ES5 (via [Nashorn](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/nashorn/)) and also does not support JS "module" concepts such as the `import` or `require` keywords.

Personally I think this is a good thing, the more JS you use, the more unmaintainable your scripts become. And there is no good way to debug. Note that Karate has syntax to do "functional style" [loops](https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops) and [transformations](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms).

Also I have found that in most of the cases where you think JS is needed, Karate's [built-in schema validation](https://twitter.com/karatedsl/status/878984854012022784) is sufficient or a *better* choice.

That said, we hope that when we switch to [Graal](https://www.graalvm.org) (proposed, and a must for Java 13+) we will be able to use ES6+ and I am personally looking forward to the arrow notation for functions.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for the answer.

I am struggling with getting a valid regex to work in Karate:
https://www.regextester.com
Regular Expression
^([1-9][0-9]{,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$
Test String
0.111111

But Karate gives me this error:
 == '#regex /^([1-9][0-9]{,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$/' OR
 == '#regex ^([1-9][0-9]{,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,6})?$' 
Illegal repetition near index 12 /^([1-9][0-9]{,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)(.[0-9]{1,6})?$/

Comment: @RichardDuinmaijer most likely you haven't escaped the back-slashes, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56502625/143475